# Passing parameters in twig (from template to another template)

Tags: symfony, twig, argument-passing

```
Parent:
       {% block row -%}{% endblock %}    
Child:
      {% block row -%}
      {{ parent() }}
      {% set boy = {
          'name': 'foo',
          'age': 12,
        }
      %}
      {% endblock %}
```

My question is, how do I pass the boy object to the Parent (without losing its value)?

Comment: Have you tried to display `boy` in the parent template? Does it give an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its a good idea to put any business logic inside your template. If you need the boy object in your parent theme, you should define it in your controller instead and pass it to the template. Both the parent and child templates can access that object.

Comment: I tried initializing the `boy object` in the controller but the issue with that was, the value of the boy object changes everytime the **Child** is called. And by the time I have any need of it (in the **Parent**), it has lost its values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
{% extends 'ProjectCommonBundle:Email:base.html.twig' %}

{# set the vars you need on your base layout #}
{% set organization = organization %}
{% set emailTo = emailTo %}

{% block body %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The value remains in it original state (but it shouldnt)

Comment: can you show us the complete code? the parent template and the child one.

Comment: I found it, instead of `{% extends` I should have used `{% embed`